# angularjs: concurrent json downloads then block prior to processing

Tags: json, angularjs

AngularJS

**Problem:** Initially download several JSON files **concurrently** then when ALL downloaded process JSON data prior to output

**Download options:** Do I use $http.get, $http.JSON, embed JSON file s JS in SCRIPT tag or Jquery?

**AngularJS processing options:** Do I use promises, callbacks or other means to block processing until all JSON files downloaded? (Please give examples)

**Goal:** 1) Minimise latency and download time 2) Follow recognise design patterns

I am a newbie to AngularJS and your help  would be greater appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

You would use promises and the $q.all method to wait for all the promises to be resolved.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

```
var promises = [];

promises.push($http.get('json1.json'));
promises.push($http.get('json2.json'));
promises.push($http.get('json3.json'));

$q.all(promises).then(function () {
    alert('all downloads finished');
});
```